# Receive firebase message in unity editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any way to receive firebase messages in unity editor. It really takes too much time to build and test application for every single change.

Comment: Well you can write code to run in the IDE as part of editing so there is potential to do something...

Comment: No, because FireBase uses Google Play Service. It means the application needs to build and run on a device that has Google Play Service on it.

Comment: And there is no any plugin for editor which would allow testing firebase in editor or something similar ?